# Android read string via USB communication

Tags: java, android, usb

I do not have much experience with USB connection in Android, so I followed the tutorial on the [Android developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html). I tried to put together a code, which when I send a command to a USB device, for example

```
send("M?");
```

then the device sends me back some rows of string which my app processes and displays it to me. But unfortunately I do not get what I want. Sometimes I get just a part of that string, sometimes some strange characters, or nothing. Could you please help me, how to fix my code? This code should be able to read small strings(for example 20-25 characters) but also long strings.

I have the following code:

**UsbReadWrite.java**

```
public class UsbReadWrite extends AppCompatActivity {

static UsbDevice device;
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
static UsbManager mUsbManager;
static PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
private static byte[] bytes;
private static boolean forceClaim = true;
static int controlTransferResult;
static byte[] readBytes = new byte[4096];
static UsbEndpoint epOut = null, epIn = null;
static UsbDeviceConnection connection;
static int recvBytes;
static String readString = "";
static Thread thread;
static Runnable r;
static UsbInterface intf;
static UsbRequest request;
Handler handler;
static UsbManager manager;
static HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public UsbReadWrite(Handler handler){

    this.handler = handler;
}
public static boolean connectDevice(Context context){

    manager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();

    if (deviceList.toString().equals("{}")) {

        return false;
    }
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    device = deviceIterator.next();
    mUsbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    try {
        context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);



    intf = device.getInterface(0);

    // look for our bulk endpoints
    for (int i = 0; i < intf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
        UsbEndpoint ep = intf.getEndpoint(i);

        if (ep.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
            if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
                epOut = ep;
            } else if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                epIn = ep;
            }
        }
    }
    if (epOut == null || epIn == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not all endpoints found.");
    }
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!mUsbManager.hasPermission(device)){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);
            connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);

            connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset
            connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Rx
            connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
            controlTransferResult = connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x4138, 0, null, 0, 0);
            connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x04, 0x0008, 0, null, 0, 0);

            request = new UsbRequest();

            request.initialize(connection, epOut);

        }
    });
    t.start();
    return true;
}

public static final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        //call method to set up device communication
                        intf = device.getInterface(0);

                        // look for our bulk endpoints
                        for (int i = 0; i < intf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                            UsbEndpoint ep = intf.getEndpoint(i);

                            if (ep.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                                if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
                                    epOut = ep;
                                } else if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                                    epIn = ep;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (epOut == null || epIn == null) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not all endpoints found.");
                        }
                        connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);
                        connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
                        connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset
                        connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Rx
                        connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
                        controlTransferResult = connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x4138, 0, null, 0, 0);
                        connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x04, 0x0008, 0, null, 0, 0);
                        request = new UsbRequest();

                        request.initialize(connection, epOut);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("MyActivity", "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

public static void read2(){

    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                readString="";
                send("M?");
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(400);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(device)){


                        recvBytes = connection.bulkTransfer(epIn, readBytes, readBytes.length, 100);
                        Log.e("Database","M?="+readBytes);
                        if (recvBytes != 0) {
                            readString += new String(readBytes);
                            readString = readString.replace("\u0001`","");
                            readString = readString.replace("\u0000","");
                           Log.e("Database","M?="+readString);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    };
    thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
}

public static void send(String command){
    String fullCommand = "@" + command + "\r\n"; /*+ "\r\n"*/
    bytes = fullCommand.getBytes();
    while (connection==null){
        continue;
    }
    connection.bulkTransfer(epOut, bytes, bytes.length, 100); //0
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.